# How to remove system backup button?

Tags: admin, backup

How to remove `Admin > syetem > tools > backup>` system backup button?

Where is `getAttributesHtml` , Thank you

```
<?= $block->getBeforeHtml() ?>
<button <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getAttributesHtml(), $block->getUiId() ?>>
    <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getLabel() ?></span>
</button>
<?= $block->getAfterHtml() ?>
```

Comment: Have you checked my answer?

Comment: not work @ChiragPatel

Comment: I solved this issue @ChiragPatel

Comment: sorry,your answer is wrong. @ChiragPatel

Comment: Ok nop, can you explain how it's wrong?

Comment: The code not in menu.xml, is in backup.php need to hide some code@ChiragPatel

Comment: I give you answer only for this `How to remove Admin > syetem > tools > backup> system backup button?` and it cumming from as given my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try below way.

For remove `Admin > syetem > tools > backup>` system backup button you need to override below file.

> /var/www/html/mdextension/vendor/magento/module-backup/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml

You can do like this.

```
<menu>
    <remove id="Magento_Backup::system_tools_backup"/>
</menu>
```

I hope it helps!